# How to force webpack to preserve async/await within the built file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

The minified bundle.js of my project (React and Typescript) contains `yield` instead of async/await. This is adding new bugs.
How to ensure the bundle keeps async/await as is?

Webpack config extract:

```
module.exports = {
  target: ["web", 'es2020'],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
  },
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./index.tsx",
  output: {
    filename: "js/bundle.[contenthash].min.js",
    path: resolve(__dirname, "../build"),
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  plugins: [],

  context: resolve(__dirname, "../src"),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.tsx?$/],
        use: ["babel-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
...
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "./@types"
    ],    
    "target": "es2019",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "es2017",
      "es2019"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js code is transformed by babel-loader which reads neither webpack target nor tsconfig. Modify your config into

```js
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.tsx?$/],
        use: ["babel-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "" /* your targeted browsers */ }]
        ]
      },
```

You could find more config in [babel-loader doc](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader), and for this simple task which doesn't involve any custom babel plugin, I'd suggest to use `swc-loader` which provides much better performance

Answer (score 0):

Following @Austaras advice I've managed to preserve `async/await` and also fix the bugs by adding another loader into the webpack config specifically for ts files:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  use: "babel-loader",
  exclude: /node_modules/,
},{
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  loader: "ts-loader",
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  options: {
    projectReferences: true
  }
},
```